# designing scroll bars css

Tags: css, scroll

I am creating a web app in which i need to design my scroll bars

```
.scroll {
        height: 550px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

this is my css

and i added my css in my main div

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl" style="background-color:#17354B;" class="myDiv container scroll">
```

i changed the following css to this

```
.scroll {
            height: 550px;
            overflow: scroll;
            color:red;
        }
```

but instead of changing the scroll bar my text inside the following div changed(i know why the text is changing)

i want to customize the following scroll bar like,(changing width,color design)
how i need to do this???

Comment: You have to add jquery for that. I would like to suggest you that use enscrollbar jquery.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge W3C standard CSS for scrollbar is not available.You can achieve it by using the -webkit-scrollbar.

```css
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
}
 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(200,0,0,1);
}
 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: grey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}



div{
  overflow : scroll;
  height : 100px;
  background-color : #eeeeee;
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    <p>Content inside div element</p>
    
    </p>
  </div>
```

Reference :
https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/